# \models\official\vision\image_classification\efficientnet\efficientnet_model.py invalid syntax

Tags: python, tensorflow

[image]

Hello, I'm trying to train my first object detection script. Using anaconda 3, python 3.5 and tensorflow 2.
I get this warning, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading python version to 3.6. Let me know if it helped

Comment: after i updated python to 3.6 i get an:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'

Comment: Upgrade to latest python 3.9. it should solve the "dataclasses" error.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in python 3.5

These steps work for me.

change every where in the code where it is mention like input_filters: int = 0 to input_filters= int(0) replace : to = and value should be in ()
Alternatively we can use script from https://github.com/vikashkum7619/efficientnet_model.

Once code is changed it will show error -> from dataclasses import dataclass
ImportError: No module named 'dataclasses',use pip install dataclasses.